# Finding Easter Eggs

Tags: visual, steganography

Can yסu find the twס special eggs?

> ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
>   ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> in the question Can y**ס**u find the tw**ס** special eggs?

Answer (score 10):

Aha

> If you click edit on Chowsen's post, the two eggs are the O in the word "two" and the O in the word "you" in the first sentence, none in the grid.

Comment: Well, _that_ was exciting!!!

Comment: heh only be 13 seconds!

Comment: @Buildstarted darn lol

Comment: What does edit have to do with it?  When I edit they look the same.

Comment: @WGroleau In my browser it looks different. Apparently it's not the normal `o`, but rather "U+05E1 Hebrew Letter Samekh", `ס`.

Comment: It's in the pססdding.

Answer (score 0):

> It's the `ס` and the `ס`! Of course!